# Why does term_run_time put my job into failed status?

Tags: autosys

From the documentation I could find, I thought term_run_time should result in a job status being set to Terminated. We have had several jobs that are terminated by this attribute, but the status is being set to Failure.

What would cause this?

Answer (score -1):

Well, *term_run_time* does terminate the job. The failure in the job might be due to other reasons. You will have to provide more details to conclude why the job failed. I suggest you to check the logs to be sure.